Bluetooth Keyboard Not Appearing in Pop!_OS
I recently purchased the Pebble K2 380S Bluetooth keyboard and I'm having trouble getting it to pair with Pop!_OS. I've followed the usual steps to troubleshoot Bluetooth connections, but the keyboard doesn't appear in the Bluetooth settings or when I scan for devices.
Here’s what I’ve already tried:
1.Ensured Bluetooth is enabled on Pop!_OS and confirmed it's working with other devices.
2.Put the keyboard in pairing mode (flashing LED) and tried connecting through Settings > Bluetooth.
3.Used bluetoothctl to scan and pair the device via the terminal, but no device shows up.
4.Restarted the Bluetooth service and cleared previous configurations.
5.Updated my system and made sure all Bluetooth drivers are installed.

The keyboard works on other devices, so I believe it’s an issue with Pop!_OS recognizing it. I’m on Pop!_OS version V and have no issues with other Bluetooth devices.
Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions to get this keyboard working?
Thanks in advance!
